# AppFog - Unauthorized source IP address

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-access-token, appfog, facebook-authorization

I host an Facebook application (https://apps.facebook.com/igoaltip/) on AppFog. Suddenly it stopped working. When I try to get information about the user using user access token (https://graph.facebook.com/me), Facebook returns OAuthException (#5) Unauthorized source IP.

I use Node.JS on server with facebook-node-sdk.

I do not specify IPs in server IP whitelist.

Comment: have documented the reason for this Fatal Error in the blog post https://apoorv.quora.com/OAuthException-Unauthorized-source-IP-address-Facebook-Application, follow the step by step guide to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently experiencing the same issues on Appfog regarding Facebook requests. AppFog might have received a block from Facebook.

We added the US east IP's of appfog to our whitelist, but for more then half an hour we still receive the same error. Stangely enough we can still use the apps tokens from other IP's. This causes me to believe it takes quite a while for Facebook to enforce the whitelist

Answer (score 2):

In Heroku, i've had the same issue, and a simple restart solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Send a support ticket to support@appfog.com and they will help you with getting your app whitelisted with Facebook. Put Facebook and Whitelist in the subject.

Answer (score 0):

According to appfog, it's something they need to take care of, you can only work around it by cloning apps, which for me isn't a solution for SoA architectured app
Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/appfog-users/K4UCWhvxGZU